# Pohozaev identity and related non-existence result for a nonlinear problem

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Is it possible to prove a [Pohozaev identity](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82728616.pdf) and the related non-existence result for non-trivial critical points of the functional

$$\int_\Omega \left(A(x,u,\nabla u) -\frac{\lambda}{2} |u|^{2} - \frac{1}{2^*}|u|^{2^*} \right) dx,$$
where $2^*$ is the critical Sobolev exponent for the embedding of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ into Lebesgue spaces?

1. Note that the functional above is the Euler-Lagrange functional of a nonlinear elliptic problem.
2. Note that the classical Pohozaev result covers the case $A(x,u,\nabla u) = \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2$.